# How Int class in python represent negative numbers

Tags: python, binary, cpu-architecture, signed-integer

Do we can view, how `class int` in python handles negative numbers by using two's complement?
I want to see source code for that not theories, I already understand how that happens in cs but I don't touch how happens in real languages.

Thankful advance for your help.

Comment: Look at the cpython source code from github.  You should be able to locate the integer arithmetic package.

Comment: I didn't find it here:https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: It's all there.  Look at [`https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/longintrepr.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/longintrepr.h) and [`https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c)